# Не получается создать вектор объектов класса

Tags: c++, классы, vector, вектор

Мне нужно создать вектор из пар `"weight, num"`, для этого сделан класс `pair`:

```
class pair
{
    int weight;
    int num;
};
```

```
vector <pair> spectre (A[0].size()); 
spectre[0].num = 1;
```

Но выдает ошибку на `<pair>`: "pair не является однозначным".
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что это значит и как это исправить?

Comment: Покажите не два отдельных куска кода, а один [mcve]. Вангую конфликт с `std::pair` - либо не испольуйте `using namespace std;`, либо переименуйте свой класс.

Comment: Это значит, что компилятор не знает какой класс ему использовать ваш `pair` или из стандартной библиотеки, который так же называется `pair`. Решение: просто переименуйте свой класс.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это значит, что класс `pair` уже определен в стандартной библиотеке.

Если это имя вам дорого, не пишите `using namespaсe std`, и используйте или `std::vector`, и т.п., или вносите только нужные имена - типа,

```
using std::vector;
using std::cin;
```

Ну, или поместите свой класс в отдельное пространство имен...

Да, и все равно работать не станет - члены класса по умолчанию `private`, так что писать `spectre[0].num = 1;` не получится...

Если имя не дорого - то переименуйте, и дело с концом...